# Showing differentiabililty at a particular point.

Tags: calculus

I am going through some review problems and I'm stuck in these problems.

> For what values of $a$ and $b$ are the following functions differentiable at $x=0$?
>
> $$(\text{i})~~~~~
> f(x) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             ax + b~&  \text{if $x \lt 0$} \\
>             x-x^2~ &  \text{if $x \ge 0$}
>         \end{array}~~~~~    \right.
> $$
>   $$(\text{ii})~~~~~~f(x) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             ax^2 + b~&  \text{if $x \lt 1$} \\
>             x-x^2~ &  \text{if $x \ge 1$}
>         \end{array}~~~~~    \right.
> $$

I know I have to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ exists in both cases but I'm having a little trouble. For example, for the first one, I get $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} (1-x) =1.$ But then I get stuck when trying to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{ax+b - f(0)}{x}.$

Please, I would like help on both problems. Thanks.

Comment: you probably meant $x\to 0^-$ where you get stuck.

Comment: yes I did. corrected.

Comment: First of all, you need to make sure that the function is continuous; in the first case this necessitates $b = 0$, right? then in the limit $x \to 0^-$ for the derivative, you will get $a$. And this should be the same as the limit from the right.

Answer (score 0):

Your work doesn't seem to help a lot since you want to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that make the functions both (first) differentiable and continuous.  You should consider the value of $x$ approaching $0^-$ and $0^+$, which leads to two cases.

---

Recall that the following [statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity) (its converse is not true) is:

> If the function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = a$, then the function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = a$.

**First Part**

Depending on the type of method required to differentiate the function, you need to take a derivative of each function in piecewise function.  We get

$$f'(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c c}
a & \text{if $x < 0$}\\
1 - 2x & \text{if $x \geq 0$}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Set $f'(0^-) = f'(0^+)$, so $a = 1$.  But by the theorem of differentiability and continuity, we also need to find the values of $a$ and $b$, such that $f(0^-) = f(0^+)$.  So

$$a(0) + b = 0 \rightarrow b = 0$$

Therefore, $a = 1$ and $b = 0$, which implies

$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c c}
x & \text{if $x < 0$}\\
x - x^2 & \text{if $x \geq 0$}
\end{array}
\right.$$

**Second Part**

This part is similar to the first.  I expect much of you to try this part by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting $a$ and $b$ to be any real number. Is that right?